# TokenMismatchException using Laravel 5.1 and VueJS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, vue.js

I am trying to use VueJS to make a POST request. But, I cannot get past a TokenMismatchException.
I have this meta tag in the main Blade template:

```
<meta name="token" id="token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

And this at the top of my VueJS file:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');
```

Here is the line in my VueJS method that invokes the POST:

```
this.$http.post('ads/create/store', this.content);
```

I have tried for way too long to get the token accepted. Can anyone out there help?

Comment: Have you inspected the request to make sure the header is being set correctly?

Comment: Header is being set... But, I don't think correctly

Comment: Does it have the csrf token as the header, you might need to use getAttribute('content') instead

Comment: The only reference I see is the X-CSRF cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I set mine up, hope it helps

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

//get the token from the meta tag
$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content');
```

Comment: Thanks! using 'value' instead of 'content' in the js was my error I appreciate your help

Answer (score 5):

You should use the 'content' attribute in the meta tag and JS `getAttribute` call:

html:

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

js:

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: Your answer was correct too...I chose @RDelorier since his came through first...I did upvote you, though. –

Answer (score 0):

Possibly easier to remember for the future, you can use

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

If you are using the blade templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a vue instance:

```
vue = new Vue({
```

Just add

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = '{{csrf_token()}}';
```

before the `$http` call

```
this.$http.post('url(change here)', this.data)
```