# How do you use laravel csrftoken in vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a vue component that contains a form with inputs - i'm using the component to submit data to laravel endpoint.

So the form is simply set up like this in a component called Sale.vue

```
<template name="sale">
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/sales/save" method="POST">
```

I already have csrftoken set up in the head tag of the containing blade file - index.blade.php

```
    <script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
    </script>
```

The index.blade yields sales page, which in turn simply contains the custom component

```
<sale v-if="showModal"></sale>
```

I would have thought since the main page has the csrftoken already, it should work.  However upon submitting the form i'm getting the `tokenMismatchException` error.

I'm using laravel 5.4 out of box setup for vue, so it contains the bootstrap.js which has the line

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
```

Not sure how that impacts as i'm not yet using ajax for the submit.

How can i get the vue component to work with the token ? Naturally, i cannot do another `{{csrf_field()}}` inside the component form and `{!! csrf_field() !!}` just prints the literal on the page?

Edit: unlike the possible dupe question, i am not as yet trying to post via Vue/ajax, i'm just trying to use standard form submit.

Comment: Does the form itself contain a `_token` field?

Comment: no im not sure where that would go ? havent seen any examples like that

Comment: Every form submitted normally, i.e. not via ajax, has a hidden input field containing the token. `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}">`. Put that in your form and you should be good,

Comment: hmm i've added that but i think im missing something in the JS section of the vue template ?

Comment: So you are using ajax? If so you need to include it in the data payload `data: { _token: <the token field value> }`

Comment: no not trying to use ajax, just standard form submit as above, but when i put your hidden field in, the console says csrf_token is not declared. So i put it in the data section of the script and that error goes but i'm still getting token mismatch

Comment: Do you have the route(s) using the csrf middleware?

Comment: hmm dont think so - can u link me to doc on how to do that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf. Use the 'web' middleware on your route/groups.

Comment: if im reading that correctly, that middleware is automatically applied ?Makes sense that it is now that i think about it cos i already used the csrftoken() in the main page and it seemed to work

Comment: Googling this question is giving hundreds of results..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TokenMismatchException using Laravel 5.1 and VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107616/tokenmismatchexception-using-laravel-5-1-and-vuejs)

Comment: @MU similar but i'm not using vuejs to do the post so slightly different